# Finding rooms of Summation

Tags: summation

Hi I was wondering how do I Solve this question. I have to solve for $a$. I can solve for it when there's one summation but now there are three. My guess is factoring out the $A$. Divide $s$ by the $3$ summations $X$ $3$.
The constants are given:
$$i = 0.03$$
$$s = 100000$$
$$n = 12$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{8}a\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}}+\sum_{k=13}^{20}a\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}}+\sum_{k=25}^{32}a\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}}=s$$

Would this be equivalent?
 $$ a = s / (\sum_1^8\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}} + \sum_{13}^{20}\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}} +$$
    $$\sum_{25}^{32}\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}})   $$

Comment: It's in the link he pasted.

Comment: Just saw the link and deleted my "Which equation?" comment. Sorry

Comment: A tutorial for writing equations on this site is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  People don't like to click through, and it makes typing an answer difficult.

Comment: Cheers bud, I'll definitely apply that the next question I got.

Comment: You can use the geometric sum formula I gave in my answer to [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689877/question-on-summation) to convert each sum into a formula without summation.

Comment: Did u know that: $(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}}=\sqrt{2}e^{i \frac{-k \pi}{4n}}$

Comment: @enthdegree:  $i$ here is not $\sqrt {-1}$.  I think it is an interest rate.

Comment: O oops, i hadnt seen that $i$ was assigned 2 some real #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factor out $a$ and insert the known values $i$, $s$, $n$ to obtain:

$$a \left( \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{8} (\frac{1}{1.03})^{\frac{k}{12}} + \sum_{k=13}^{20} (\frac{1}{1.03})^{\frac{k}{12}} + \sum_{k=25}^{32} (\frac{1}{1.03})^{\frac{k}{12}}}_{3\,geometric\,series} \right) = 100000$$

I assume you know how to calculate sums of geometric series. Divide 100000 by their sum and you have found $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the number of terms in each sum is the same, so you can write $$\sum_{k=1}^{8}a\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}}+\sum_{k=13}^{20}a\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}}+\sum_{k=25}^{32}a\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}}=\\ \left(1+(1+i)^{\frac{-12}n}+(1+i)^{\frac{-24}n}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{8}a\cdot(1+i)^{\frac{-k}{n}}$$ and the part in the big parentheses is a geometric sum as well.  It looks like you are paying off a loan over three years with eight payments per year and four months of no payments.